# Javascript hoisting - David Shariff quiz

Tags: javascript

The question is, what will the following alert:

```
function bar() {
    return foo;
    foo = 10;
    function foo() {}
    var foo = '11';
}
alert(typeof bar());
```

and the answer is, function.

My questions:

1. Isn't bar() being replaced by its return value? If no, why?
2. Isn't foo = 10; being hoisted to the top? (hoisting)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only declarations are hoisted in JavaScript.

For `function` declarations, that includes their entire statement body (which is empty in the case of `foo`). However, with `var`s, the assignments aren't considered part of the declaration and will remain where the statement was placed. <sup>(2)</sup>

To the engine, `bar()` appears to be:

```
function bar() {
    // hoisted
    function foo() {}
    var foo;          // no-op, `foo` was already declared by `function foo() {}`

    // remaining statements
    return foo;

    // unreachable code following a `return`
    foo = 10;
    foo = '11'; // separated from `var foo;`
}
```

The resulting `typeof` being `function` is referring to the type of `function foo() {}`, a reference to which is what `bar()` returns. <sup>(1)</sup>

```
alert(bar().toString()); // "function foo() {}"
```

Comment: @GeorgeKatsanos [No operation or change.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP) In this case, the `var` won't do anything with `foo` since it's already been declared as a `function` ([§10.5, steps 5 and 8.c](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.5)).

Comment: So if I get it straight, the reason function is returned on alert, is because of hoisting which places the foo declaration before the return takes place. Many thanks, that clears it up. I was checking https://gist.github.com/MattSurabian/8867307 and his explanation is not the same or not clear enough. What do you think?

Comment: @JonathanLonowski He asked something.

Answer (score 6):

You can look at it this way:

```
function bar() {
    var foo = function() {};
    return foo; // function ends here
    foo = 10;
    foo = '11';
}
```

The other two assignment statements aren't happening.